# How can I use localtime with setInterval()?

Tags: javascript

I use `setInterval(5*60*1000)` for calling my fucntion every 5 minutes, but the problem is if I open my webpage at 00.03AM, the time that function will be called is 00.08AM.

So, I want my function is called follow the localtime, I mean time in real life. For example, if I open my webpage at 00.03AM the function will be called at every 5 minutes such as `00.05AM, 00.010AM, 00.015AM, ...`

Or, in other words, how can I get my function to run at the next 5 minute point within the hour and then run every 5 minutes after that.
Please suggest me how to do that thing. Thank you.

Comment: depending on how exact you want to be, consider running your function at intervals of one minute and having it check to see if the current time is a multiple of five

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I'd do is check the time every minute, but only execute something if the time is a multiple of 5 minutes.  Something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if(new Date().getMinutes() % 5 == 0){
    // Do something
  }
}, 60*1000)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works !!!. But there are some delay just 2 up to 3 seconds before (after sometimes) it calls the function again. So, I added more fuction: `if(new Date().getSeconds() == 0)` to call the function for the exactly 5 minutes.

Comment: If you did that, don't forget that you'd need the `setInterval` to run every second!

Comment: Yes I did. Thank you again :)